# Integrating UITabBarController with slide menu in iOS Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to create slide menu (left side). I am using `UITabBarController` as `rootViewController`.

Please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: Did you googled it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I have tired MMdrawer but no luck while integrating it with UITabbarcontroller.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to use left menu slider while using UItabbarcontroller. I am making Uitabbarcontroller as my rootviewcontroller. So third party MMdrawer which i am using also set in as rootviewcontroller. So I am confused how to implement this...:(

Comment: @webo80 If you have any idea how to implement this pls let me knw asap. Thanks..!!

Comment: There are lots of controls available on web. Check this on [github](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

Answer (score 0):

I found this is very neat solution for nib and I'm using it for my own project. You may check it out: https://maniacdev.com/2013/08/open-source-component-for-making-a-nice-ios-7-control-center-style-animated-side-bar-menu